# Каково происхождение слова «недоумение»?

Tags: этимология, приставка

> **НЕДОУМЕНИЕ,** -я; ***ср.*** Состояние, вызванное непониманием, неясностью чего-л. *Остановиться в недоумении. С недоумением слушать
> кого-л. В глазах отразилось н. Высказать н. в связи с нарушением
> графика.*
>
> [[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x)]

Можно ли выделить в этом слове приставку *недо-*?

> **недо-** ...
> *неол.* при добавлении к существительному образует существительное со значением неполноты, некачественности ◆ недобанк , ◆ недоделка
>
> [[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE-)]

Если таким образом представить слово, то получается «недо-умение», т. е. неполнота умения, как «недо-понимание» — неполнота понимания.

Но ведь исходя из первого определения: «недоумение» — это состояние вызванное непониманием, а не неумением.

Почему же так? Какова этимология этого слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этимология восходит к слову "ум", а не к слову "умение" ("ум" и "умение" родственны). С церковнославянского, например, слово "недоуменный" переводится как "непознаваемый".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я тоже думал над словом «ум», однако нигде не нашёл подтверждения. Насчёт церковнославянского вы правы. Я Вам поставил «Ответ полезен», но хотел бы получить больше информации. Вы говорите, что «„ум“ и „умение“ не родственны», а какой же корень тогда лёг в основу «умения»? Может быть «умение» изначально значило: «то, что было познано умом»?

Comment: В нескольких этимологических словарях написано, что «умение» происходит от «ум». Например, словарь Шанского Н. М. : «Уме́ть. Общеслав. Суф. производное от умъ…».

Comment: Так же интересно, что в словаре Даля В. И.: «Уметь, **знать, понимать, разуметь;** мочь, быть способну, сведущу в чем, иметь навык, быть чему выучену, знать делать что, работать, быть в чем искусну».

Comment: Если принят, что «уметь» когда-то значило «знать, понимать, разуметь», то «недоумение», можно трактовать как «незнание, непонимание, неразумение».

Comment: @Eagle да, я имел в виду "родственны", конечно. Отрицательную частицу я забыл удалить, когда переформулировал ответ.